# Can I write if statements in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner at coding and I wanted to create a function that looks something like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = int(input("What is your age = "))
def prize(a):
    for n in range(20, 61):
        if 20 < n <= 30:
            print('If you are between 20 and 30 years old, you will receive only', a[1], 'prize')
```

As of right now, my code doesn't print anything even if I input a number between 20 and 30. I know I have to use the return statement for this to be able to actually run, but I wanted to know is there a way that I can write multiple if statements inside of a function? And for them to be actually able to run?

Comment: Your issue is that you're not running the function. You've only defined it. Try adding `prize(a)` to the end of your file

Comment: @NathanWride Hi thank you for your comment but what do you mean by 'the end of my file'?

Comment: See Fedor Soldatkin's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forgot to call the function.

Yes, you can write as many `if` statements as you need:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = int(input("What is your age = "))
def prize(a):
    for n in range(20, 61):
        if n == 30:
            print('You are 30 years old')
        elif n == 40:
            print('You are 40 years old')
        elif 20 < n <= 30:
            print('If you are between 20 and 30 years old, you will receive only', a[1], 'prize')

prize(a)
```

Comment: Do not use `is` instead of `==`. They are not the same, and `is` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @DYZ Please, don't downvote this. In that case `30` and `40` are immutable constants. I know, what does `is` do, and i was not try to compare variable with other variable or mutable object. However, i will edit my answer, I think you meant that it may confuse beginners. Thank you for the reply!